# Error Creating new project in Angular 7.2.1

Tags: angular

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OfYRq.png)I am creating a new project the usual way after upgrading from Angular 6 to Angular 7.2.1

I got the following error after: ng new employeemanager

Schematic input does not validate against the Schema: {"name":"employeemanager"}
Errors:

Data path "" should have required property 'version'.

Comment: can you run 

    ng new employeemanager --verbose=true 

and post the output here

Comment: I got the same output from before.

Comment: was this the only string you are getting ? can you post a screenshot ?

Comment: I added a screenshot there's a link. I tested Angular 6 before it created a new project but version 7 I am getting these errors.

Comment: just try and give a different name first like ng new test

Comment: @knowiz have try to change name type of your project i think error is occurred from name type.

Answer (score 0):

I have updated my cli to the latest version to verify if the issue is caused because of cli or project name, but There wasn't any issue on my machine. I guess package on your local machine might have become corrupted, I have checked cli error logs on npm as well, no one has faced this issue yet. What you can do next is reinstall cli clean npm cache or verify if above version 6.

```
npm uninstall -g @angular/cli (add sudo in the start if using Linux)
npm cache clean --force / npm cache verify
npm install -g @angular/cli
```

I am sure this should fix above issue.